# Javascript change element properties onmouseover onmouseout

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got this code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.thumbspiccolimabelli').hover( function(e){

     var ider = $(this).attr('title');  // e.g. the other element I want to change colour on 
     console.log(ider);

     var test = document.getElementsByClassName(ider);
     for(var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
         if(test[i].style.color = 'red'){
            test[i].style.color = 'white';
         }
         else{
            test[i].style.color = 'red';
         }
     }
     console.log(test);

    });
  });
</script>
```

And i'm trying to change the colour of all element on the page that have the id of the element i'm hovering over, but it does'nt quite work.

The element im hovering over has a ID of "myhoverelement" and I have span elements that share the same ID, these ones I want the colour to change on.

Thanks

Comment: You don't want to give different elements the same `id`. `id`s are supposed to be unique so you can access them. If you think a bunch of different elements will share a similar property, use a `class`

Comment: IDs must be unique; only one element can have an ID. You need to use classes.

Comment: I've update to use classname, so it now changes color to white on hover but where do I put the onmouseout function to change back to black?

Comment: I ended up using Jquery(...) it was much simpler, thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

You dont need javascript for this

CSS:

```
.thumbspiccolimabelli {
    background-color: none;
}

.thumbspiccolimabelli:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?
'#myhoverelement' is being replaced with '.myhoverelement'. IDs must be unique.

```
$('.thumbspiccolimabelli').on('hover' , function() {
    $('.myhoverelement').each(function() {
        $(this).css('background' , '#ffffff');
    });  
});
```